# Interchanging closed operators and integrals

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I am dealing with a problem in Evans PDE without measure theory knowledge...

We have contraction semigroup $\{S_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ on real Banach space $X$, i.e family of bounded linear operators from $ X \to X $ which satisfy:

1) $S(0)u = u$ $\text{ }$ for all $u \in X$

2) $S(t+s)=S(t)S(s)u = S(s)S(t)u $ $\quad$($ t,s \geq 0$, $u \in X $)

3) mapping  $t \mapsto S(t)u $ $\text{ }$ is continuous from $ [0,\infty) $ into $X$

4) $||S(t)|| \leq 1$

We have infinitesimal generator A of the contraction semigroup $\{S_t\}_{t \geq 0}$,
$$ A: D(A) \to X $$
$$  Au:= \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{S(t)u-u}{t} $$
where $$D(A)= \{ u \in X; \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{S(t)u-u}{t} \text{ exists in } X \}. $$

I have to prove
$$ A \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}S(t)u dt = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}S(t)Au dt$$
for all $u \in D(A).$

From theory i know $ S(t)u \in D(A)$, $AS(t)u = S(t)Au$, $D(A)$ is dense in $X$ and $A$ is closed. The hint in the book is to approximate the integral by a Riemann sum.

Edit: 
I tried as it was suggested to me:
$$
I:=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)udt \quad \text{and} \quad J:=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)Audt.
$$ 
I have to prove $A(I)=J$. I define
$$
I_n = \int_0^{n}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)udt \quad \text{and} \quad  J_n=\int_0^{n}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)Audt.
$$
Therefore $I_n \to I$ and $J_n \to J$. I approximate $I_n$ and $J_n$ with the help of Riemann sums. Divide the interval $[0,n]$ in $k$ parts of length $\frac{n}{k}$. Function $e^{-\lambda t}$ is monotonically decreasing and thus reaches its maximum on the interval $[\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}]$ at $\frac{i}{n}$. The approximation with upper Riemann sum for integral $I_n$ is 
$$
I_n = \int_0^{n}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)udt \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]}S(t)u
$$
and for integral $J_n$ is
$$
J_n = \int_0^{n}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)Audt \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]}S(t)Au
$$
Is this OK?

Then i define sequences $\{ I_{n,k} \}_k = I_{n,1},I_{n,2},\dots$ and $\{ J_{n,k} \}_k = J_{n,1},J_{n,2},\dots$ where 
$$
I_{n,k} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]}S(t)u
$$
and
$$
J_{n,k} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]}S(t)Au
$$
Then $I_{n,k} \to I_{n}$ when $k \to \infty$ and $J_{n,k} \to J_{n}$ when $k \to \infty$. Here i also struggle...Is the following true?
$$
A(I_{n,k}) = A(\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]}S(t)u) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]}AS(t)u
$$
I know $A$ is linear ($Au=\lim_{t\to 0+} \frac{S(t)u-u}{t}$) but what can i do with the $\max$?

I then use a proven fact in the book, $AS(t)u = S(t)Au$ to get $A(I_{n,k}) = J_{n,k}$.
I have $A(I_{n,k}) \to J_n$ and since $A$ is closed i have $A(I_n) = J_n$. Therefore $A(I_n) \to J$. Using again closedness of $A$ i conclude $A(I)=J$.

Comment: Do you know how to do it when the upper bound $\infty$ is replaced by some $R>0$? To do that, use Riemann sums and the properties of $S$. To deal with your case use the fact that $A$ is closed.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Thank you. Since this comment was helpful i somehow proceeded but i am still missing some steps. Could you take a look at my problem that i state in a comment to the answer of Christopher. Thank you

Comment: @ZulfiqarIII
No, it's not pointless, how can you divide an unbounded interval in finite equal subintervals? There are 2 limits to be taken here.

Comment: I don't understand why you write an inequality by approximating integral with Riemann sum. You are working in a Banach space which may be $\mathbb{R}$ or not but no kind of order endow the space. You should find a sequence of step X-valued functions convergent to yours

Comment: This was 3 and a half years ago. My memory is weak here. I am working in a very different field these days - actuarial science. I managed to pass this course, though. I got an 8 - It was a master of Math program in Amsterdam. I was an Erasmus student :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have it. You just have to approximate the interval with Riemann sum where you take arbitrary value in the intervals of the partition...

For example,
$$
I_n = \int_0^{n}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)udt \approx \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda t_i}S(t_i)u
$$
where $t_i \in [(i-1)\frac{n}{k},i\frac{n}{k}]$.

Everything else should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a general outline of what the hint in the book is intending: Let $I,J$ be the two integrals. You want to show $A(I) = J$. Let $I_n$ and $J_n$ be the two integrals reduced to the interval $[0,n]$. Then $I_n \rightarrow I$ and $J_n \rightarrow J$. Now, see if you can approximate $I_n$ and $J_n$ by further sequences $I_{n,k}$ and $J_{n,k}$ using Riemann sums. You will need to use the fact that $A$ is a closed operator in order to take limits and ultimately prove $A(I) = J$.

Comment: Vote up. It was helpful. I define $I_n = \int_0^{n}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)udt$. Approximating with upper Riemann sum gives me $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]}S(t)udt$$ and similarly $J$, in particular $$J_{n,k} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{n}{k} e^{-\lambda(i-1)\frac{n}{k}}\max_{t \in [\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]}S(t)Audt.$$ My problem is now argumenting $A(I_{n,k})=J_{n,k}$. This boils down to $A(\max S(t)u) = \max AS(t)u$...I don't even know what $A(\max S(t)u)$ is. Could you help me again?